# openlayers clustering is very slow with ever changing positions

Tags: javascript, openlayers

when using a clusterSource in openlayers (5/6) i can cluster features nicely.

Except the vectorsource that is the source of my clustersource changes data constantly.
I have a websockets that feeds me positions of stuff (like ships in marinetrafic or airplanes on flightradar24)
I got the feeling with every change in the underlying source, my clustering gets done all over.
Is there a way to postphone that update? or call it manually?

I can buffer the input stream and process a higher number of messages at once (like 1000 position updates every 3 seconds)
And i want the clustering to happen AFTER i processed those 1000 messages.
It gets so slow now that i got the feeling it happens every message (so 1000 times every 3 seconds)

An other optimalisation would be to only cluster the items that are currently visible (with a buffer around the edges the side of the cluster distance)
That would save a lot of calculation in my opinion.

Anyone here can help me out?

right now i got something like this (in meta-code):

```
const features = {};  //my own reference collection
const buffer = [];  //it's get filled somewhere else (constantly)

function processBuffer() {

  //here we like to pause the clustering logic

  buffer.forEach(function(message){
    let feature = features[message.id];

    if (feature) {
      //existing feature
      feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(message.coord);
    } else {
      //new feature
      feature = ... create feature ...
      vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
    }
  });

  //here we like to continue the clustering logic

  //reset buffer
  buffer.length = 0;
}

setInterval(processBuffer, 3000);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting all your features in a buffer/array/collection then using `.clear()` and `.addFeatures()` to update the source?

Comment: it is this simple indeed @Mike. Can you  post this as an answser, i can accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing all the features in the source via an array using `.clear()` and `.addFeatures()` should be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37006016/2296579) it states that **not** every feature change causes a redraw, instead a redraw is requested and will only be done on the next animation frame.

There are also some suggestions what can be done to improve performance although clustering is not explicitly.

I suggest measuring the run time of the loop, if it takes to long the map might actually not be rendered often enough and thus feel unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many data you should not show them all.

- Use min-max resolution for vector-layer
- Dont send data from server that you cant show them in your instant bbox.